# IIS Log Analysing -IP address and status Codes

Tags: parsing, iis-7.5, logging

Is there any way to find out what all status codes a host got when tried to access the particular website.

Something like

28-10-2010  192.168.1.1  HTTP 404     http://localhost/BAC/default.aspx
28-10-2010  192.168.1.10  HTTP 200    //localhost/BAC/default2.aspx1

I tried using some free log analysers like : IIS Log Analyser,IIS Log Parser etc,but no luck

**Any idea on how to implement the same?Is there any free tool that fulfills this kind of a  requirement**

A sample IIS log file entry is like

2010-10-28 04:49:52 127.0.0.1 POST /Abc/Ocsii2.asmx - 80 - **127.0.0.1** Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+2.0.50727.4952) **200** 0 0 127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using LogParser for that, it includes a command line that is very powerfull and allows you to issue "SQL-like" queries to the logs (and many other sources, like files, event viewer and others). I have shared a few common queries that it can help with:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosag/analyze-your-iis-log-files-favorite-log-parser-queries)